# Misplaced footer due to a lot of content

Tags: html, css, layout

This is the problem I'm having:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UByFU.png (cant directly post due to no rep)

I've managed to get my wrapper (the overall border) to expand with the large amount of words on this page, but now my footer has gone all weird.

Here is a condensed version of my HTML & CSS:

http://pastebin.com/rb7ftatN (both in one link due to no rep)

PLEASE HELP ME GUYS. I'm really new at HTML / CSS and i am a perfectionist so it really gets on my nerves when things don't work, im sure some of you guys can relate.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you take out `right: 2px;` from the footer, does this still happen? Also, fiddle please.

Comment: What's the problem in words? That the footer is creeping up into the text?

Comment: a couple different options suggested, but it will depend on how you want the foot to act over different content and future design.  `clear:both` is the easiest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just an inline-block might do it, as in

```
footer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 980px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 44px;
    position: relative;
    right: 2px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: this worked too! ill have to have a muck around with yours and publ1c's answers but thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the footer to be below the text, use a `clear: both;`

In your case:

```
footer {
    /* THIS IS THE MISPLACED FOOTER */
    width: 980px;
    height: 40px;
    /* Other Rules*/

    clear: both;
```

}

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nv8Wd/2/) demonstrating it.

Comment: this worked, thanks !!! i probably should have specified where i wanted the footer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always want the footer visible, use a Position of fixed...

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    /* Other rules */
}
```

This will glue the footer to the screen